# Omnet++ : How to get the output gate from an inout gate?

Tags: omnet++

I am using omnetpp to construct a process-oriented discrete event simulation where I am hooking components up via channels programatically (not using ned). For this, I create an inout channel in one of my modules but I want to get the output port of the inout channel so I can connect it in my application via the connect method. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain output port from `inout` gate one may use `gate()` method adding `$o` to the gate name. For example, if the `inout` gate has name `lowerLayer`, the output part will be returned using:

```
cGate *gate = gate("lowerLayer$o");
```

Reference: [Simulation Manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:gate-objects)

Comment: I like the gateHalf (equivalent method) better. Thanks for the pointer.